# How to call a Java method through JNI letting the JVM garbage-collect the arguments?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, java-native-interface

I have a native application that starts a JVM and calls some methods through the JNI API.

Roughly, the native application:

1. starts the JVM;
2. creates a new frame with [`PushLocalFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#PushLocalFrame);
3. builds a Java object `x`, calling constructors via JNI;
4. pops off the frame with [`PopLocalFrame(x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#PopLocalFrame);
5. calls a long-running function `foo(x)` in the JVM, passing the created object as argument with [`CallObjectMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Call_type_Method_routines);
6. terminates.

The problem is that in same cases step 5 crashes with a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. This is unexpected, because usually that Java function does not use much memory when it is called from a JVM-only application.

Taking heap dumps with VisualVM I found that there many "GC roots (Java frame)" that I didn't expect. My best explanation is that:

1. `foo` takes some fields from `x` and stores stuff in them;
2. during the execution of `foo` the JVM can not garbage collect `x`, and transitively whatever is stored in it.

So, **is there a way to call a Java method through the JNI interface, letting the JVM garbage-collect the arguments?**

[Weak global references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#weak_global_references) are almost what I want, but I don't see how to use them because in theory they can be garbage-collected immediately after creation, before being passed as argument in a function call.

Answer (score -1):

When dealing with native resources you shouldn't count on the garbage collection to free up your memory.

Instead, implement the `Closable` interface for every Java class that wraps a native object or handle, and make sure to close every object before dereferencing it.

You may use the `try (<Allocate Closables Here>) { <Use Them Here> }` syntax for auto-closing objects.